# *ngIf causing issue in messagebox closing

Tags: angular

In semantic-ui , close Icon not working with *ngIf. If you remove *ngIf , it start working.  What am I missing ?

```
  <div class="ui info message" *ngIf="message" >
          <i class="close icon" ></i>
          <div class="header">

          </div>
           <p> {{message}}</p>
      </div>
      </div>

//Javascript code
  $('.message .close').on('click', function() { $(this).parent().hide(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
*ngIf="message?.length > 0" // For lists or string.
```

Use:

```
*ngIf="message" // Only if message is boolean
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't mixed up the code with jQuery if you're using angular. Angular also has click event - (click). Suppose if you want to hide the parent div when the icon is click you can try this

```
<div class="ui info message" *ngIf="message" >
          <i class="close icon" (click)="hideMessage()"></i>
          <div class="header">

          </div>
           <p> {{message}}</p>
      </div>
      </div>
```

In the component

```
message: boolean = true;

private hideMessage() {
     this.message = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code with this one and this will word.

```
$('.message').on('click','.close', function() { $(this).parent().hide(); });
```

****but i will suggest to use (click)="someFunction()" in your template

Comment: this too is not working.  I am taking your suggestion though as suggested by digit below. thx